# How use yield results with pool in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, yield, pool

I'm having a question on how to use yield to allocate a large symmetric matrix in parallel. Since each item is relatively fast to process, the best way I found it was by paralleling each row.

Below is a **brief example** of the problem I'm having when using yield with imap_unordered.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import numpy as np

def func(param):
    i, js = param
    for j in js:
        yield i,j,random.random()

N=100
M = np.eye(N, dtype=np.float)
params_parallel = [ (i, range(i)) for i in range(N) ]

with mp.Pool(processes=4) as p:
    for (i,j,value) in p.imap_unordered( func, params_parallel ):
        M[i,j] = M[j,i] = value
```

I am having the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_parallel.py", line 15, in <module>
    for (i,j,value) in p.imap_unordered( func, params_parallel ):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 761, in next
    raise value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<generator object func at 0x7fb6ae377780>'. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle generator objects",)'
```

ps.: I can't use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

Comment: The yield isn't really what you want to use here it looks like, make it a regular turn statement and it'll work.

Comment: I get like a gazillion other errors, how exactly are you using this?